# Transform smarty Boolean value to human readable value.('Yes'/'No' or 'True'/'False')

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, smarty

I'm using Smarty to generate some tables, and at one point I'm printing out variable values that have been passed from php file. The problem is that some of these variables are Boolean values and they render as "1" or "". This was my attempt to transform these Boolean values to a human readable format. It does not work. How can can I check if a variable is a Boolean value?

```
{if $val2.$value_index === true}Yes
{else if $val2.$value_index === false}No
{else}{$val2.$value_index->value}{/if}
```

Comment: I'm not exactly familiar with this, but it looks as though that should be `$va2.$value_index->value === true`

Comment: @Jeff suggest your comment as an answer. I feel silly that I just didn't type it out correctly.

Comment: So easy to do - I've had plenty of mistakes like this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not exactly familiar with this, but it looks as though that should be:

```
{if $val2.$value_index->value === true}Yes
{elseif $val2.$value_index->value === false}No
{else}{$val2.$value_index->value}{/if}
```

Answer (score 5):

Use the PHP [var_export()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.var-export.php) function as a smarty modifier for your boolean variables.
Set the second parameter to true, so [var_export()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.var-export.php) returns the variable representation instead of outputting it.

To check if your variable is a boolean, use the PHP [is_bool()](http://php.net/manual/de/function.is-bool.php) function.

Your Smarty code should look like this:

```
{if is_bool($val2.$value_index)}
  {$val2.$value_index|var_export:true}
{/if}
```

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
{if $va2.$value_index}Yes
{else}No
{/if}
```

> The problem is that some of these variables are Boolean values and they render as "1" or "".

`1` and `""` aren't boolean values, they are an integer and a string correspondingly.

Comment: problem with the above it will make most variables appear as Yes. Most of the variables are strings, only a few are Boolean.

Comment: Then you have screwy schizophrenic variables.  Fix them.  :)

Comment: Haha :) It is intentionally mixed for abstraction purposes

Answer (score 0):

I googled shorthand for if else, and this post came at first. Just in case some one needs a shorthand for:

```
{if $val2.$value_index === true}Yes
{else if $val2.$value_index === false}No
{else}{$val2.$value_index->value}{/if}
```

to:

```
{($val2.$value_index->value) ? 'yes' : (!$val2.$value_index->value) ? 'no' : $val2.$value_index->value}
```